# Error when adding random values column to Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I want to rename columns of my DataFrame in Spark 2.2 and print its content using `show()`, I get the following errors:

```
18/01/04 12:05:37 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'cluster' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/04 12:05:37 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'project' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/04 12:05:37 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'client' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/04 12:05:37 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'twitter_mentioned_user' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/04 12:05:37 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'author' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 
18/01/04 12:05:37 WARN ScalaRowValueReader: Field 'cluster' is backed by an array but the associated Spark Schema does not reflect this;
              (use es.read.field.as.array.include/exclude) 

18/01/04 12:05:37 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 7)
scala.MatchError: Buffer(13145439) (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: Buffer(13145439) (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
```

I printed the schema and it looks as follows:

```
df_processed
  .withColumn("srcId", toInt(df_processed("srcId")))
  .withColumn("dstId", toInt(df_processed("dstId")))
  .withColumn("attr", rand).printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- srcId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- dstId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- attr: double (nullable = false)
```

The error occurs when I run this code:

```
df_processed
  .withColumn("srcId", toInt(df_processed("srcId")))
  .withColumn("dstId", toInt(df_processed("dstId")))
  .withColumn("attr", rand).show()
```

It occurs when I add `.withColumn("attr", rand)`, but it works when I use `.withColumn("attr2", lit(0))`.

**UPDATE:**

```
df_processed.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- srcId: double (nullable = true)
 |-- dstId: double (nullable = true)
```

`df_processed.show()` does not give any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the similar example that you are trying to do, To cast the data type you can use `cast` function

```
  val ds = Seq(
    (1.2, 3.5),
    (1.2, 3.5),
    (1.2, 3.5)
  ).toDF("srcId", "dstId")

  ds.withColumn("srcId", $"srcId".cast(IntegerType))
    .withColumn("dstId", $"dstId".cast(IntegerType))
    .withColumn("attr", rand)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UDF function:

```
val getRandom= udf(()=> {scala.math.random})
val df2 = df.withColumn("randomColumn", getRandom())
```